# Android Fragment memory leak

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have a problem of memory leak in my application.
I'm testing it with 2 fragments in witch in the first one I create a big variable (ArrayList arr = new ArrayList(10000000);) in order to see if memory will be empty on changing fragment (the second one is empty), but unfortunately this doesn not happen.

Activity is a ActionBarActivity and when I change fragment I do remove(fragment) and popbackstack, but the memory increase every time I change.

Please Help me!!!!

Here below I post some code: Activity is ActionBarActivity and it has a side menu NavigationDrawer:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
   private Toolbar mToolbar;
   private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
   private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
       mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
       setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
       mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
       mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
       setActionBarMenu(true);
       selectItem(1);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
           ft.remove(fm.findFragmentByTag(fm.getFragments().get(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getTag()));
           fm.popBackStack();
        }
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                onChangeFragment(new UsersCheckInFragment(), false);
            case 2:
            etc...
        }

        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        selectItem(position);
    }

    public void onChangeFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, ((Object) fragment).getClass().getSimpleName());
        if (addToBackStack)
            ft.addToBackStack("");
       ft.commit();
    }
}
```

And the fragment:

```
public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false);
        mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(10000000);
        return view;
    }
}
```

And here some screen of memory

[first fragment](http://imageshack.com/a/img905/7828/lIKsGF.png)

[second fragment](http://imageshack.com/a/img908/827/6YQkeg.png)

[again first fragment](http://imageshack.com/a/img661/5521/mYqtFm.png)

Comment: Pose some code and logs so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Done. I've posted code and screenshots of memory.

Comment: What happens if you changed fragments multiple times? Is it possible that the garbage collector has not yet triggered yet?

Comment: You mean a behaviour like that f1->f2->f1->f2?

Memory remains about 70mb, so it not increase more, even if for a while it try to go down. (http://imageshack.com/a/img537/3650/BjMlOA.png)

Comment: I don't think that is a memory leak, A memory leak would continue rising with every cycle.  Also what is up with the loop going through the back stack?

Comment: I have noticed that if I call System.gc() when fragment is changed, the memory follow another behaviour: it goes always until 70mb, but after calling the garbage collector it goes down to 30mb, but then again 70. It seems that garbage collector is not called the first time..

The loop is for remove all fragments in the stack

Comment: while (fm. getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) { fm.fm.popBackStackImmediate(); } Your code is trying to remove each fragment twice.

Comment: Don't worry about this and let android handle this for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a memory leak, the garbage collector will be called by the system eventually. There is no requirement that the system immediately remove the fragments from memory when you are finished with them.